# Uniqueness of holomorphic function given some conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

I've encountered the following problem. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the open disc $D(0,3/2)$, that is, the open disc in the complex plane with center at $0$ and radius $3/2$. This function satisfies the following conditions:

- $|f(z)|=1/2$ if $|z|=1$.
- $z=0$, $z=1/2$ and $z=-1/2$ are the only zeros of $f$ in $D(0,1)$ and they are simple.
- $f'(0)=1/8$

The only function $f$ that verifies all these conditions is:

$f(z)=-\dfrac{z}{2}\bigg(\dfrac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{z+1/2}{1+z/2}\bigg)$

True or false?

I suspect it is true, but I don't know how to prove it. Initially I thought that, defining $g(z)$ as $f(z)$ in $\overline{D}(0,1)$ and as $|z|f(z)$ in $D(0,3/2)\setminus \overline{D}(0,1)$, I could disprove it, but I doubt that $g(z)$ is holomorphic in $D(0,3/2)$.

Any advice? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is another such function then $q=f/g$ is holomorphic, since $f$ and $g$ have the same zeroes. Also $|q(z)|=1$ when $|z|=1$...

**Details:** Since a disk is simply connected, $q=e^L$ for some holomorphic $L=u+iv$. Now $u(z)=0$ for $|z|=1$, hence $u=0$, so $v$ is constant. So $q$ is constant: $f=cg$. Now $f'(0)=g'(0)\ne0$ shows $c=1$.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I must be missing something. I can indeed conclude that |q(z)|=1 on the unit circumference, but I don't know how to proceed from there. I suppose that, if this statement is true, then the radius 3/2 is irrelevant, and that it would hold for any radius r. So if a function is constant on the unit circumference, its zeros inside are simple, finite and known, and you also know the value of the derivative on the origin, then the function is unique on any disc centered on the origin? There must be some theorem I'm forgetting about.

Comment: $q$ has no zero. So $q=e^L$, $L=u+iv$. Now $L(z)=0$ for $|z|=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I see how to finish from there. But every holomorphic function without zeros can be written in the form of an exponential?

Comment: If the domain is a disk, or any simply-connected region, yes.

Comment: Typo above, too late to edit: Should have said $u(z)=0$ for $|z|=1$, not $L(z)=0$.